# Decline does not shut the project as it could be resurrected

Tags: community, opportunity, customization

We have an Opportunity declined in Feb 2015 but a sales ops can still change the closed date for that opportunity as Jun 2016. So Decline does not shut the project as it could be resurrected? How this can be resolved. 
Really appreciated if someone could help as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a validation rule (Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Validation Rules):

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Declined")
```

This will prevent any edits to a record once it has been marked as declined. You may need to adjust this formula for your business requirements.